# Is there a way to get more than 10000 subscribers name per day using YouTube Data API?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

I need to get the name of all subscribers of a YT Channel which has 6 Million subscribers but YouTube Data API only allows me to get 10 thousand names\requisitions per day, it would take me 2 years to get all the names this way.
Is there any other way I could do this task faster?

This is the API I've been using so far:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

P.s - I have full access to this channel, Oauth 2.0 included.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per [official accounts](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172325507#comment4) given by Google staff, one cannot get from the API more than 1000 of his/her subscriber meta-data entries (the emphasis below is mine):

> ***Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)***
>
> This is an intended behavior, the team informed that we *only allow 1000 results to be returned through the Subscriptions.List API*. So, what you're seeing is an expected behavior of the API.
> However, a documentation update is needed here to clarify the existence of a limit and make the necessary changes. The team is working on updating the public documentation to reflect this.

This is unfortunate, but a fact (yet to be documented by the official YouTube Data API specs).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `mySubscribers=true` with `part` containing `subscriberSnippet`.
I don't understand why you are saying that you are limited to 10 000 subscribers a day. Indeed YouTube Data API v3 allows 10 000 requests a day (quota cost of [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) is about 1 unit) ok but a request can retrieve strictly more than a single item (default: 5).

Have you tried using `maxResults=50` which would requires you 12 days instead of almost 2 years?

Comment: Unfortunately, @Benjamin Loison, your answer in wrong. By design -- yet not documented officially --, one cannot get more than 1000 -- that is one thousand -- entries of his/her subscribers list. (See my answer to this question.)